# SSIS 2012: How to Count by Key?

Tags: ssis

I have a dataset where a key value is duplicated.  In the example below, order numbers are duplicated each time there is a status change by a different group (Hold column).

```
Order #   |   Hold
-----------------------
123456    |    H1
123456    |    H2
564653    |    H1
```

There are many examples on how to remove duplicate but I actually want to count them.  What I want to see is this:

```
Order #   |   Hold  | Count
----------------------------
123456    |    H2   |   1
123456    |    H1   |   2
564653    |    H1   |   1
```

The holds have no time value and the date can be the same date.  The order of the counts don't matter so for 123456, H1 could have have the 1 and H2 could have the 2.  Maybe count isn't the correct term.

How do I achieve this in SSIS 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER() function ..

```
declare @tablename table (OrderNum varchar(10), Hold varchar(3))

insert into @tablename (OrderNum, Hold)
select '123456', 'H1'
union all
select '123456', 'H2'
union all
select '564653', 'H1'

select 
    OrderNum, Hold,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by OrderNum order by Hold DESC) as [Count]
from @tablename
```

FYI ..
If you want to order then change `order by Hold DESC` to `order by Hold ASC`